# GNU+Intel openmp dynamic loading

Tags: r, shared-libraries, openmp, intel, dynamic-linking

I have been trying to create an R library **dynamically** loading a dependency using Intel OpenMP. When the library is loaded, there is a clash with OpenMP library.

Using `KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE` gets me past the loading error but the program crashes once it is in a parallel section.

Unfortunately, neither compiling R using intel OpenMP or the dependency using GNU OpenMP is an option (because I want it to work with the standard R distribution and some external dependencies linked statically have to use Intel OpenMP).
However, I can recompile the dependency with some compatibility flags or modify how linking is done (but in the end, it has to be loaded dynamically from the R library). Setting environment variables is also an option (I am thinking about https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522775 but none of the options seems to help so far).

The R library is written in C and I doubt that the fact it is R which will load it in the end really matters.

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Are you following the requirement either to always use icc/icpc rather than gcc/g++ or ld on your link steps, or if not, always force linking of the Intel OpenMP library before any library search which may load libgomp?  I see no reason to use Intel OpenMP unless using Intel compiler to build some of your objects.  The shared library you create should have no specific OpenMP library in it, so, if it used only gcc/g++ and no icc/icpc/ifort, it could be linked against either OpenMP.

Comment: Actually, we are compiling our dependency objects with gcc and linking with ld but we could do it with icc. We have to keep libiomp because of additional dependencies (compiled with icc). However, R and the library have to be compiled with gcc. Also, R 3.4+ loads GNU OpenMP on start and before we have a chance to load the library.

Comment: Can't you use LD_PRELOAD to load Intel OpenMP first?

Comment: If you have to use libiomp then I strongly suggest to link with `icc` or `icpc` (the latter if you have C++ code using the standard library). The problem here is that Intel has its own versions of the libraries (even gcc libraries) in its installation path. In addition, it makes additional transformations and links against additional libraries using `-qopenmp` flags. I remember several situations where trying to link with `icc` instead of `ld` solved the problem straight away.